# Get summaries of repeated consecutive values by row in R

Tags: r, apply, na, summary

I´m trying to get some statistics (min, max, mean) of repeated values by row in R.

My dataframe looks similar to this:

```
b <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=7, nrow=3, 
     c(3,NA,NA,4,5,NA,7,6,NA,7,NA,8,9,NA,NA,4,6,NA,NA,7,NA), byrow = TRUE))
```

For each row, I want to add a column with the min, max and mean of the no. of columns containing consecutive NAs and it should something like this

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 max min mean
1  3 NA NA  4  5 NA  7   2   1  1.5
2  6 NA  7 NA  8  9 NA   1   1  1.0
3 NA  4  6 NA NA  7 NA   2   1  1.33
```

This is just a small example of my dataset with 2000 rows and 48 columns.

Does anyone have some code for this?

Comment: Why is the mean `1.5` in row 1. Shouldn't it be `(1 + 1 + 2)/ 3`?

Comment: Are you referring to the statistics about the number of consecutive columns containing NA per row? For row 3, the mean would be (1+2+1) / 3 = 1.33, right?

Comment: Yes you're correct I just divided by the wrong number in the example

Comment: Can you update your post with the correct expected output?

Comment: It´s now corrected Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `apply` over the rows and get the "runs" of non-NA columns. Once you have that, you can simply take the summary stats of those:

```
b[,c("mean", "max", "min")] <- do.call(rbind, apply(b, 1, function(x){
                                                      res <- rle(!is.na(x))
                                                      res2 <- res[["lengths"]][res[["values"]]]
                                                      data.frame(mean = mean(res2), max = max(res2), min = min(res2))
                                                    }
                                                      ))

 b
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7     mean max min
#1  3 NA NA  4  5 NA  7 1.333333   2   1
#2  6 NA  7 NA  8  9 NA 1.333333   2   1
#3 NA  4  6 NA NA  7 NA 1.500000   2   1
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` solution with `rle`which computes the lengths of runs of equal values in a vector.

```
library(dplyr)
b %>% cbind( b %>% rowwise() %>% do(rl = rle(is.na(.))$lengths[rle(is.na(.))$values == T])) 
   %>% rowwise() 
   %>%  mutate(mean = mean(rl),
               max = max(rl),
               min = min(rl)) 
   %>% select(-rl)


#      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7   max   min  mean
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1     3    NA    NA     4     5    NA     7     2     1  1.50
# 2     6    NA     7    NA     8     9    NA     1     1  1.00
# 3    NA     4     6    NA    NA     7    NA     2     1  1.33
```